# Is there easier way to use bulk_create() with many query to instance create items

Tags: python, django

I don't know basic programming at all and just learned python and Django a few months ago, due to an urgent need I decided to create my own program to support my department and team
After the program is running, I want to make it easier for the user and after I look around it is recommended to use bulk_create and ajax JavaScript, definitely not using JavaScript.
After looking for ways to use bulk_create, I find it inefficient like:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Audit, id=766)

item1 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=1)
item2 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=2)
item3 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=3)
item4 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=4)
item5 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=5)
item6 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=6)
item7 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=7)
item8 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=8)
item9 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=9)
item10 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=10)
item11 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=11)
item12 = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=12)

audit_mie = [

    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item1,kategori=item1.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item2,kategori=item2.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item3,kategori=item3.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item4,kategori=item4.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item5,kategori=item5.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item6,kategori=item6.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item7,kategori=item7.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item8,kategori=item8.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item9,kategori=item9.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item10,kategori=item10.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item11,kategori=item11.kategori.kategori),
    AuditItem(audit=instance,item=item12,kategori=item12.kategori.kategori),
]

AuditItem.objects.bulk_create(audit_mie)
```

is there an easier way besides the method above?

if not, then I stick with it, by creating objects in each item id which is approximately 130 (currently) and I will group it into 8 (currently) bulk_create() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list to hold all your items and a for loop to iterate through them.

```
items = []
audit_mie = []
instance = get_object_or_404(Audit, id=766)

#the range is the starting and ending range, it will count from 1 to 12
for i in range(1,13)
    tmp = (get_object_or_404(Item.objects.filter(aspek=instance.aspek_audit).filter(active=True),id=i))
    items.append(tmp)
    audit_mie.append(AuditItem(audit=instance,item=tmp,kategori=tmp.kategori.kategori))

AuditItem.objects.bulk_create(audit_mie)
```

A for loop iterating through a list would allow you to go to a specific item if needed using `items[1]` or whatever item you specifically want to access if needed.
[This resource should help you understand lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) if needed and [this should help with for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

Comment: my mistake as a beginner is not learning the basics of python well and tends to finish quickly as is often used, namely "instance" lol btw after I tried it by directly using it with the url it will definitely repeat the function. and finally I turned it into an ajax button and it worked! it's just that when I click 1x it is still ok it renders perfectly the second click turns out to add a new list below it, I can just manipulate the button on or give a warning "just click once" lol once again I am very grateful to you